# Need help in DataGridView UserDeletedRow event handler

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Sorry if this seems a bit unprofessional but I have no idea whats going on here and its driving me crazy.

So I have a DataGridView with data which looks like this :-

[image: one]

What I want to do is whenever the user deletes a row (or entry) I want all the rows below it to update its SrNo and Balance fields accordingly for which I have written the following code in the UserDeletedRow event handler function :-

(Note that deleting the first row is disabled)

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            for (int i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) - 1;
                int a = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                int b = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = (a + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[4].Value)) - b;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem I am having is when the user deletes the last row, the if condition made to check specifically that is not working properly. Or should I say

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

Is not returning the proper value (so I think) because when I place a breakpoint on the If condition I see this

[image: two]

and this on the watchlist

[image: three]

We can see that the selected row (or current row) is Index number 5 yet on the watchlist it shows 4, this is the root of my problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you Try the SelectedIndex instead of current row?
 if(dataGridView1.SelectedIndex != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)

Comment: @GaAd there is no such property as selectindex and selectedrows[0].index returns an error

Comment: Ok that means that the row is already deleted. I think you want to manipulate the table before the row is deleted. Did you try a different event like on RowDeleting?
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)

Comment: @GaAd there is no such event as rowdeleting but there is one called userrowdeleting, should i try that?

Comment: You are using a gridview right in asp.net with c#. There should be an event in gridview tab,
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowDeleting="GridView_RowDeleting">

Comment: @GaAd I am using WinForms

Comment: O ok you didnt specify that and i cannot see your images as well. Yes please try UserDeletingRow and keep the same code as above

Comment: @GaAd I had to modify the code but it works now. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: No worries man! Glad it worked for you. Want me to add it on answers?